# Backbone model change event not firing after setting model

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I took an non kosher approach and used the `$.ajax()` for an ajax file upload because at the moment I can't figure out the "backbone" way. The picture has been uploaded and the ajax request sends back the new backbone model in JSON, populated with the filename of the new photo. However the model is not firing a `change` event so I can't populate the profile picture. See the `success` function below.

```
    getFile:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        that = this;
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        name = file.name;
        size = file.size;
        type = file.type;
        var formData = new FormData($('#upload-child-pic-form')[0]);
        console.log(this,'currentUploadU',this.currentUpload);
        formData.append('child_id',this.currentUpload);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/children/upload/',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function() { 
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if(myXhr.upload){ 
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(data){
                        $("#upload-child-pic-progress").val(data.position / data.totalSize * 100);
                    }, false); 
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //Ajax events
            beforeSend: function(data){
                $("#upload-child-pic-progress").removeClass('hide');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#upload-child-pic-progress").addClass('hide');
                $("#add-child-profile-pics-modal").modal('hide');
                var sentData = $.parseJSON(data);
                var thisChild = that.children.get(sentData.id);
                thisChild.set("photo",sentData.photo);
                thisChild.trigger('change');
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log('error',data);
            },
            // Form data
            data: formData,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    },
```

Comment: _because at the moment I can't figure out the "right" way._ I would ask a question about the _right_ way.

Comment: Technically the question isn't about the "right way". It's  why the model is not firing a `change` event when the model is set. Although I would love to know the correct way to do this in Backbone.

Comment: what shows the line: `var thisChild = that.children.get(sentData.id);`
is `thisChild` undefined ?

Comment: No `thisChild` is not undefined. It is the right model.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing var before the that variables and other variables...

having these variable global is a menace, they can be changed/overwritten outside of this scope before the success callback is called.

```
that = this; //should be - 'var that = this;'
```